# is it possible to position push-pin images over another image using percentage relative positioning

Tags: javascript, css, image, css-position

I'd like to have a map of the country with push-pins for every state capitol location, and would like to have the country map be resizable, so that when it was made larger or smaller, the push pins would automatically be moved to the correct new location on the screen.

**Is this possible with percentage positioning?** I've only been able to position the push-pin on top of the other image if the push-pin is given an absolute position, but then I have to recalculate the push-pin position on resize.

Is there any way to put the push-pin at `top: 50%; left 50%` relative to the country map image or to the div that contains the country map image?

Comment: BTW they're "capitals", not "capitols". The "Capitol" is the name of the legislative building in Washington DC, which is the capital of the USA.

Comment: @Diodeus: The state buildings are also called capitols.

Answer (score 1):

In general:

Set the wrapping element to `position:relative.` This sets the origin point for absolutely-positioned children

Set the child element to `position:absolute` and provide `top:` and `left:` (or right: and bottom:) in pixels.

For a push-pin you probably want to set a CSS background, instead of an inline image.

```
<div class="pin pinA"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.pin {
   position:absolute;
   height:20px;
   width:20px;
   background-image:url(...);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

...then use a second class for positioning:

```
.pinA {
     top:50px;
     left:300px;
}
```

You can then continue to make entries for pinB, pinC etc.

Comment: Wouldn't the absolute positioning of the pin require  recalculation of its top/left coordinates when the country map was made larger or smaller?

Comment: Yes it would, but dealing with half-pixels also offers its own set of challenges.

Comment: I am trying to avoid having to recalculate the pixels. I have that working already, sort of, but it is not perfect, and the push-pins tend to wander along a diagonal.